# Error using SingleClientConnManager and AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm very new to android programming and I've been stuck with this code for days now. 
The error I get is "Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated." - and I understand why this occurs, but not how to solve it. The code I am working in:

```
protected class loader extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username_in",username.getText().toString().trim()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password_in",password.getText().toString().trim()));
        tv.setText("Started onPreExecute");

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.myurl.com/phplogin.php");

            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            response=httpclient.execute(httppost);

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found"))
            {
                httppost.getEntity().consumeContent();
                //startActivity(new Intent("com.example.obligatorisk.BROWSER"));
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        tv.setText("Reached onPostExecute");
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}
```

Full error log:

```
10-18 14:30:52.134: W/SingleClientConnManager(3940): Invalid use of SingleClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
10-18 14:30:52.134: W/SingleClientConnManager(3940): Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
10-18 14:30:52.414: W/System.err(3940): org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Internal Server Error
10-18 14:30:52.414: W/System.err(3940):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:71)
10-18 14:30:52.424: W/System.err(3940):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:59)
10-18 14:30:52.424: W/System.err(3940):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:657)
10-18 14:30:52.424: W/System.err(3940):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:627)
10-18 14:30:52.424: W/System.err(3940):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:616)
10-18 14:30:52.424: W/System.err(3940):     at com.example.obligatorisk.MainActivity$loader.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:113)
10-18 14:30:52.424: W/System.err(3940):     at com.example.obligatorisk.MainActivity$loader.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
10-18 14:30:52.424: W/System.err(3940):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-18 14:30:52.434: W/System.err(3940):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-18 14:30:52.434: W/System.err(3940):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-18 14:30:52.434: W/System.err(3940):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
10-18 14:30:52.443: W/System.err(3940):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-18 14:30:52.443: W/System.err(3940):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-18 14:30:52.443: W/System.err(3940):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

The idea behind the project is to make a login function for an application.

I keep trying to find solutions and help on the web but I can't figure this out no matter what I try. I really hope someone would take their time to help me out here. If you need more information about the code, errors etc. please tell me and I will add it.

Thank you, and thanks to everyone who has been helping me out earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You're only doing the `httppost.getEntity().consumeContent();` if the response is equal to "User Found". You have to consume the content completely regardless. Move that method call outside of the conditional.

```
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found"))
    {
        //startActivity(new Intent("com.example.obligatorisk.BROWSER"));
    }
    httppost.getEntity().consumeContent();
```

Comment: I tried to do so, but I still get the same error.

    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
    final String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found"))
    {
        startActivity(new Intent("com.example.obligatorisk.BROWSER"));
    }
    httppost.getEntity().consumeContent();